# How can a resistor be given a positive and negative characteristic?

Tags: resistors, diodes, electromagnetism, charge, theory

This question is not pertaining to a circuit, but to individual parts itself.

1. If for any reason, i want to make a resistor have a positive and negative charge on its either ends, what would be the approach for this? How can they be turned into something like a capacitor, which has a cathode and an anode. Could this be done magnetically?
2. Can a diode be turned into a resistor of some value? Or like a capacitor? At least theoretically.

Comment: What happens when, instead of a resistor, there's just a wire with opposite charges at each end. What happens to the charges? How will things be different when there is a resistor. Can the charges still move? I am not getting the point of your question. *Can a diode be turned into a resistor?* Will a goldfish turn into a parrot if you glue some feathers on it? If a diode behaves as a resistor then how would it still be a diode?

Comment: Its a mostly theoretical question, maybe something like a laboratory experiment. I wanted to ask how the wire (or resistor) would be given that positive and negative charge, in practice.

Comment: Before wasting your time on these "theoretical exercises" you would do better spending time trying to understand how the components work. With that knowledge it will be easier to see that your question makes little sense.

Comment: There is an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> If for any reason, i want to make a resistor have a positive and negative charge on its either ends, what would be the approach for this?

Break the resistor somewhere in the middle and position the parts very close together but not touching. You now have a very small capacitor with an equivalent series resistance of the R value.

> Can a diode be turned into a resistor of some value?

Exceed its current rating for some time and it should fail short-circuit. Your resistor value will be that of the series connection of the metal to semiconductor junctions and the semiconductor inside and << 1 Ω.

> Or like a capacitor?

If you reverse bias a diode it will behave like a capacitor. The capacitance figures are quoted in the diode datasheets. Varicap diodes were common in FM tuners several decades ago. I don't know if they're commonly used anymore.

Comment: My experience in turning diodes to resistors has thus far mostly produce resistors with rather **high** resistance value.

Comment: Ok. @Transistor Thank you for your answer, its great.

Comment: @Oldfart What procedure did you follow?

Comment: @Vibhu Both transistor and oldfart are somewhat jokingly referring to breaking diodes, which tends to result in something mostly resistive. This is not something you should actually do; the end result is very difficult to predict and definitely not going to have a datasheet.

Comment: Varicap diodes (I see them called varactors more often) are still used in current technology. In fact, there was a professor working on antenna design at my university not too long ago who was researching a design with one in the middle of an antenna to allow programmatically altering the antenna's characteristics--that stuff all goes over my head though.

Comment: @Hearth they were talking about breaking the resistor to induce a capacitance (for a p n charge)... :-) ... That antenna project seems quite sophisticated, thanks for comment...